# How can we control error pages in Jetty Websocket with Camel

Tags: websocket, apache-camel, jetty, jetty-8

We are using Apache Camel Jetty Websocket 2.17.1 with jetty 8.

We went through PCI scan and in this we found it is returning 404 pages with resources like

```
       <html>
         <head>
             <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
             <title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
         </head>
         <body>
             <h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2>
             <p>Problem accessing /TOKENIZE.. Reason:

                 <pre>    Not Found</pre>
             </p>
             <hr />
             <i>
                 <small>Powered by Jetty://</small>
             </i>
         </body>
     </html>
```

I changed this for Jetty Apache Camel component with errorHandler. But not able to change or trace the error page content returned on response with HTTP /GET.

PCI guys tried sending /GET  for websocket port and app is returning above 404 content.

FYI. I also set Error Handler in **ServletContextHandler**.But Still my error handler is not pickedup.

Answer (score 0):

[Jetty 8 (now EOL/End of Life)](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html) did not have the `ErrorHandler` wired up correctly for odd behaviors like HTTP Upgrade only paths (which websocket in jetty 8 is).

Jetty 9.x has overhauled the `ErrorHandler` to work for all request errors that reach the same context path as the `ErrorHandler`.

Which means that the only kinds of errors that currently do not go through the `ErrorHandler` in Jetty 9.x+ are ones that do not reach a context.  Such as bad HTTP requests resulting in a 400 status code or proxy requests.